# Getting a Windows credentials username in c# windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-embedded

How do I get the currently signed in username in a windows forms application?
The app runs on Windows Embedded Standard 7 O/S.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You probably want `Environment.UserName`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx for details.

Comment: For those looking for domain\user, this can be supplemented with Environment.UserDomainName.